# Erro ao usar login do Facebook repetidas vezes

Tags: php, facebook

Estou usando a API do Facebook para cadastrar dados no banco de dados. Assim que abro e navegador dá tudo certo, mas quando tento fazer o cadastro mais de uma vez aparece esse erro:

[image: Uncaught excepetion 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The defautl access token must be of type "String" or Facebook\AccessToken']

Depois que fecho o navegador volta ao normal, então acredito que seja problema ao ler os dados em *SESSION*. Segue meu código:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once("php/conexao.php");
    require_once __DIR__ . '/lib/Facebook/autoload.php';

    $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => '**********',
      'app_secret' => '**************',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
      ;

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    //print_r($helper);
    $permissions = ['email'];

    try {
        if(isset($_SESSION['face_access_token'])){
            $accessToken = $_SESSION['face_access_token'];
        }else{
            $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
        }
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    if(!isset($accessToken)){
        $url_login = 'https://fidecard.net/conclui_cadastro_cliente.php';
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($url_login, $permissions);
    }else{
        $url_login = 'https://fidecard.net/conclui_cadastro_cliente.php';
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($url_login, $permissions);

        if(isset($_SESSION['face_access_token'])){
            $fb -> setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['face_access_token']);
        }else{
            $_SESSION['face_access_token'] = (string)$accessToken;
            $oAuth2Client = $fb -> getOAuth2Client();
            $_SESSION['face_access_token'] = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['face_access_token']);
            $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['face_access_token']);
        }


        try {
            // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
            $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=name, email');
            $user = $response->getGraphUser();
            $nome_cliente = $user['name'];
            $email_cliente = $user['email'];
            $cpf_cliente = $_SESSION['cpf_cliente'];

            $result = "UPDATE cliente SET email_cliente = '$email_cliente', nome_cliente = '$nome_cliente', confirma_email_cliente = true WHERE cpf_cliente = '$cpf_cliente'";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($link, $result);          
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
          echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
          echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
          exit;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Se possível clique em [edit] e poste o erro no formato *texto*.

Comment: Qual é a linha 41? O token é uma sequencia de números?

Comment: Após `$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['face_access_token']);` adicione `$_SESSION['face_access_token'] = (string)$accessToken;`

Comment: linha 41 é essa:         if(isset($_SESSION['face_access_token'])){
           $fb -> setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['face_access_token']);
        }

Comment: @VictorFialho você já tentou a dica acima?

Comment: Tentei, não funcionou, parece que não está reconhecendo como string, mas deveria ser uma string